# Twitter Bootstrap 3.1.0: multiple visible-*

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3.0.3, one could use multiple `visible-*` classes to explicitly hide some content according to the device width.

Unfortunately, with the release of Bootstrap 3.1.0, this is bugging and content is hidden at the wrong width (eg. at medium size instead of small, despite the use of `visible-md visible-lg`). Please see http://bootply.com/109923 for a demo.

Anyone has a quick-fix or explanation for that?

### Solutions

1. Quick-fix by @Natsu: use `.hidden-*` classes instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be to instead use the `.hidden-*` classes:

```
<ul class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2135/

It appears that `.visible-lg` is overriding `.visible-md` at the medium breakpoint:

http://linenwoods.com/test.png

Comment: Great, thanks! I did not even try `.hidden-*` classes, assuming that would be the same problem... Nice quick-fix.

Comment: @mhavel: Not a problem!